# mapreduce job fails on AvroKeyInputFormat only on a cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have some map-reduce working fine on y local machine.

When I run the job on a remote cluster, I get this error :

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getInputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)
```

My local machine runs `2.7.0` `hadoop` version and on my remote cluster I have `2.8.1` `hadoop` version

Where does this error may come from ?

Comment: Kindly check my answer and upvote/accept, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says `ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat`

It means that a required apache avro library is missing in classpath.

Hadoop picks the jar files from the path emit by below command:

```
$ hadoop classpath
```

By default it list all the hadoop core jars.

You can add your jar by executing below command on the prompt or add to the shell script for executing the map-reduce.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/my/apache_avro_jar.jar
```

After executing this, try checking the class path again by `hadoop classpath` command and you should be able to see your jar listed along with hadoop core jars.

Try to execute the program again.

Another option is to create a fat jar of the program by including apache avro jar.

3rd option is to add Apache Avro jar into mapreduce classpath by adding it via `DistributedCache`.

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(avroJar, conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be very less probable but you might double check your dependency :

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
```